# Google map with asp.net and Markers loaded dynamically are not working on IE

Tags: javascript, google-maps, internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3

I have this custom google map, with dynamic markers read from SQL server,

> it works fine on chrome

, but when using IE, it gives me an error with this file https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/15/8/main.js

> the error is in main.js, line 25 character 911,,    Out of stack space
>   ....

Also I am using the google map marker cluster.

here is a link to the site with the issue http://aprilit.com/gmap/default.aspx

I am stuck and don't know what to do, please HELP..

here is my js file that calls json and list the markers on the map

> > var map;
> >
> > function LoadMap(arrMarkers) {
> >
> > ```
> > var mapOptions = {
> >     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
> >     streetViewControl: false
> > }
> >
> > var MarkerShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('img/assets/markershadow.png',
> >       new google.maps.Size(51.0, 37.0),
> >     new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
> >     new google.maps.Point(16.0, 18.0));
> >
> > var MarkerShape = {
> >     coord:
> > ```
> >
> > [20, 0, 21, 1, 22, 2, 23, 3, 24, 4, 24, 5, 25, 6, 25, 7, 25, 8, 25, 9,25, 10, 25, 11, 25, 12, 25, 13, 25, 14, 24, 15, 23,16, 23, 17, 22, 18, 20, 19, 21, 20, 24, 21, 27, 22, 29, 23, 30, 24,30, 25, 30, 26, 29, 27, 29, 28, 27, 29, 24, 30, 21, 31, 13, 31, 12, 30, 12, 29, 12, 28, 11, 27, 11, 26, 11, 25, 11, 24, 11, 23, 12, 22,12, 21, 11, 20, 10, 19, 9, 18, 8, 17, 7, 16, 6, 15, 6, 14, 5, 13, 5, 12, 5, 11, 5, 10, 5, 9, 5, 8, 5, 7, 5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 4, 7, 3, 8, 2, 9,1, 11, 0, 20, 0],
> >             type: 'poly'
> >         };
> >
> > ```
> > var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
> >
> > var markers = [];
> >
> > var tempCount = 0;
> >
> > var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
> >
> > for (var XMLCount = 0; XMLCount < arrMarkers.length; XMLCount++) {
> >     var Points = $.parseXML(arrMarkers[XMLCount]);
> >
> >     $Markers = $(Points).find("Marker");
> >
> >     for (var i = 0; i < $Markers.length; i++) {
> >
> >         var tempID = $Markers.find('mid')[i].innerHTML;
> >
> >         var tempCID = $Markers.find('cid')[i].innerHTML;
> >
> >         var myLatLng =
> >                     new google.maps.LatLng($Markers.find('lt')[i].innerHTML,
> >                 $Markers.find('lg')[i].innerHTML);
> >
> >         markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
> >             position: myLatLng,
> >             map: map,
> >             animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
> >             shadow: MarkerShadow,
> >             shape: MarkerShape,
> >             markerid: $Markers.find('mid')[i].innerHTML,
> >             catid: $Markers.find('cid')[i].innerHTML,
> >             icon: LoadIcon($Markers.find('cimg')[i].innerHTML)
> >         }));
> >
> >
> >         infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
> >             content: "loading..."
> >         });
> >
> >         google.maps.event.addListener(markers[tempCount], 'click', function () {
> >
> >          infowindow.setContent('<div style="font-family:tahoma;font-size:10pt;height:30px;"><img
> > ```
> >
> > src="img/assets/loader.gif"/> Loading..');
> >
> > ```
> >             infowindow.open(map, this);
> >
> >             $.ajax(
> >              {
> >                  type: "POST",
> >                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
> >                  url: "Markers.asmx/GetMarker",
> >                  data: JSON.stringify({ MarkerID: this['markerid'], CategoryID: this['catid'] }), //{conType:"'"
> > ```
> >
> > +ContentType+ "'",conID:"'" + ContentID + "'"}, //
> >                          dataType: "json",
> >                          success: function (msg) {
> >
> > ```
> >                      infowindow.setContent(formatInfoDivHTML(msg.d));
> >                  }
> >              });
> >
> >             map.panTo(this.getPosition());
> >             infowindow.open(map, this);
> >         });
> >
> >         bounds.extend(myLatLng);
> >         tempCount++;
> >     }
> > }
> > map.fitBounds(bounds);
> >
> > var mcOptions = { gridSize: 50, maxZoom: 12 };
> >
> > var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
> >
> > google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); } function LoadIcon(MarkerImage) {
> >
> > var ImagePath = "Images/Categories/" + MarkerImage;
> >
> > var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(ImagePath,
> >          new google.maps.Size(32.0, 37.0),
> >         new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
> >           new google.maps.Point(16.0, 18.0));
> > return image; }
> > ```
> >
> > function formatInfoDivHTML(xmlMarker) {
> >
> > ```
> > var Marker = $.parseXML(xmlMarker);
> >
> > var ImagePath = "Images/Marker/" + $(Marker).find('mimg')[0].innerHTML;
> >
> > var URL = "ViewMarker.aspx?id=" + $(Marker).find('mid')[0].innerHTML; ;
> >
> > var html = "<div style='font-family:tahoma;font-size:10pt;'>";
> >
> > html +=  "<img style='width:100px;height:100px;margin:1px 6px 0 0;border:1px solid #ccc;float:left;padding:1px;' src='" + ImagePath +
> > ```
> >
> > "' />";
> >
> > ```
> > html += "<strong style='font-size:12pt;'>" + $(Marker).find('t')[0].innerHTML + "</strong><br/><br/>";
> >
> > html += "<p style='margin-left:6px;'>" + $(Marker).find('intr')[0].innerHTML + "</p><br/>";
> >
> > html += "<a href='" + URL + "'> View Details</a><br/>";
> >
> > html += "</div>";
> >
> > return html; }
> >
> > function LoadMarkers(CatID) {
> >
> >    $.ajax({
> >                  type: "POST",
> >                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
> >                  url: "Markers.asmx/GetMarker",
> >                  data: JSON.stringify({ MarkerID: -1, CategoryID: CatID }), 
> >                  dataType: "json",
> >                  success: function (msg) {
> >                      if (msg.d != "")
> >                          LoadMap(SplitXML(msg.d));
> >                      else
> >                          alert("No Markers related to this category!");
> >                      }
> >        });   }
> >
> >
> >
> > function SplitXML(xmlstring) {
> >
> > xmlstring = xmlstring.replace(/<Markers>/g, "");
> >
> > xmlstring = xmlstring.replace(/<\/Markers>/g, "");
> >
> > xmlstring = xmlstring.replace(/<\/Marker>/g, "#");
> >
> > var xmlMarkers = xmlstring.split('#');
> >
> > var markersXMLArr = [];
> >
> > var xmlCollection = "<Markers>";
> >
> > var j = 1;
> >
> > for (var i = 0; i < xmlMarkers.length; i++) {
> >     if (xmlMarkers[i] != '') {
> >
> >     xmlCollection += xmlMarkers[i] + '</Marker>';
> >
> >     }
> >
> >     if (j < 5 && i != xmlMarkers.length - 1) {
> >      j++;
> >         }
> >     else {
> >
> >         markersXMLArr[parseInt(i / 5)] = xmlCollection + "</Markers>";
> >
> >         j = 1;
> >
> >         xmlCollection = "<Markers>";
> >     }
> >
> > }
> >
> >  return markersXMLArr;
> >
> > }
> > ```

The Call for the map will be like this

> LoadMarkers(-1);

thanks

Comment: There's lots of little syntax errors in [your javascript](http://aprilit.com/gmap/JavaScript/LoadMarkers.js), which won't help IE much.  Run it through something like [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) to identify and fix them.

Comment: Nothing is a stopper,,, and the bug is not in my code,, plus using the same script worked on this page on IE http://aprilit.com/gmap/addmarker.aspx,,,  but anyway,, thanks

Comment: IE complains about `</p>` after `</ul>`. W3C validator complains about `<ul>` markup (among a lot of others). What happen if you delete `<p>...</p>` around `<ul>...</ul>` part?

Comment: @MoBdair _'the bug is not in my code'_... in which case what do you expect to gain by asking questions here?  File a bug with [Google Maps](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/), [IE](https://connect.microsoft.com/ie) or the [Google MarkerClusterer group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-maps-utility-library-v3)

Comment: Downvote for not posting example code to reproduce the issue.  We can't help you without seeing the code in question.  Really good questions show the most pertinent lines on SO and also offer a JSFiddle/Plunkr/CodePen repro that we can easily fork and troubleshoot.  You get out of SO what you put in.

Comment: @Anto Jurovic I mean the the error appears not from my files...@Steve Jansen I didn't post my code because It works normally on other browser, though I'll update the post for your reference..THanks all

Comment: this code is unreadable for me. Wall of text ;x

Comment: @szpic now I hope you can read better,,

Comment: @AntoJurković I removed the <p> and nothing happened

Comment: The issue appears to be in Map.fitbounds,, when I remove it it does not the out of stack space error... any hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue,,

It appears that IE doesn't support the innerHTML property I used here:

> $Markers.find('mid')[i].innerHTML

or any where else where I am retrieving the data from my xml fields.

so it had to be replaced with the the  textContent property as this:

> $Markers.find('mid')[i].textContent;

and that solves the whole issue.!!

thanks for your help guys